# Arbitrary deep network structures in Keras

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I'm new to Keras. Is it possible to write arbitrary deep learning graph structures using Keras (say something like Faster R-CNN model)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Keras 1.0 has the functional API, and older versions of Keras have a graph API. Implementing Faster R-CNN with them is pretty easy.

More information at [this guide](http://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/). You should prefer the functional API since it is easier to use and the prefered way. The Graph API was removed in Keras 1.0 I believe.

Comment: @NaimishAgarwal If this answer helped you solve the problem, please mark it as accepted (click the check mark below the answer's up/down vote buttons). Thanks.

Comment: I don't think function API is a good answer to Faster R-CNN implementation on Keras

Comment: @eric2323223 You have to tell us why you think that, else its just an opinion with no value.

Comment: I think a simple model of Faster R-CNN using Keras functional API should be a better answer.

Comment: @eric2323223 That sounds the same as what I answered.